# Realm Android DB Filtering

Tags: android, realm

I am using `RealmDB` as my `Android Local Storage`. But, filtering is not working fine for me. E.g: If I've `GOOGLE` in the `DB` if I query for `google` it wouldn't show it up. If I've `Google` if I query for `google` same thing. Unless the name is well typed. I've tried to lower case my own result to filter. All to no avail. I extend a `BaseAdapter` to use in my `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                //String query = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                mResult = filterStates(constraint.toString());
                Log.e(TAG, "" + mResult.size());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    }

    @NonNull
    private List<RealmOutlet> filterStates(String query) {
    Realm mRealm = RealmUtils.getRealmInstance(mContext);
    return mRealm.where(RealmOutlet.class)
            /*.equalTo("channel", "distributor")
            .equalTo("isSent", true)*/
            .beginGroup()
            .equalTo("name", query)
            .or()
            .contains("name", query)
            .or()
            .beginsWith("name", query)
            .endGroup()
            .findAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering this seems to be the same code as https://gist.github.com/sdex/83b75ce9c2f2e2654bec ,
I think it should work if you replace

```
@NonNull
private List<RealmOutlet> filterStates(String query) {
Realm mRealm = RealmUtils.getRealmInstance(mContext);
return mRealm.where(RealmOutlet.class)
        /*.equalTo("channel", "distributor")
        .equalTo("isSent", true)*/
        .beginGroup()
        .equalTo("name", query)
        .or()
        .contains("name", query)
        .or()
        .beginsWith("name", query)
        .endGroup()
        .findAll();
}
```

with

```
@NonNull
private List<RealmOutlet> filterStates(String query) {
Realm mRealm = RealmUtils.getRealmInstance(mContext);
return mRealm.where(RealmOutlet.class)
        .contains("name", query, Case.INSENSITIVE)
        .findAll();
}
```

Although opening a new instance over and over again is bad practice.

Comment: It's not working. I noticed all the names in my db are all capital letter. So if you want to search `GOOGLE` `Google` wouldn't work `google` wouldn't work only `GO` would show you a suggestion. The only solution I'm seeing here is, if by anyway I can do a toLowerCase() on the data

Comment: That's why you should specify `Case.INSENSITIVE`

Comment: Exactly. I did add that. And same thing

Comment: Can you verify that `publishResults()` successfully runs, and you receive the results, but the results is empty?

Comment: You see. I am very sorry for the inconvinience. I was editing the wrong file and checking for result in the wrong place. Thank you very much. It works fine.